# Vaulted Bathroom Ceiling HVAC Woes

Tags: hvac, insulation, ceiling

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/gallery/YRjRbHf)

In the process of remodeling our master bathroom. The bathroom has a vaulted ceiling with the skylight. There’s only one register and it’s on the back wall.

The bathroom is consistently showing as 8 degrees higher than any other room in the house.

Does anyone have any suggestions to keeping the temperature more consistent?

Insulation looks good, R30 all around the skylight and vault from the attic

The only register is an 8 inch flexible duct coming from the main trunk in the attic. Would I benefit by splitting that off into 2 6” registers?

Would I need to run another takeoff from the trunk?

Comment: You have already had answers at that site  you just dont like them. The culprit is the skylight, fix it at the source with a reflective film.